# chrome.app.isInstalled always returns false for Google Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

why does  chrome.app.isInstalled always return false for Google Chrome extensions?

Dynamically I add a link element on page load:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">
```

The following is some Javascript that executes when a button has been clicked:

```
if (!chrome.app.isInstalled) {
 alert('extension is about to be installed!');
 install_extension();
}else{
  alert('extension is installed already.');
}
```

The first time I clicked the button, Google Chrome asked me if I wanted to install the extension. I agree and the extension was installed correctly. When I refreshed the page,  I clicked the button once again and Google CHrome asked me to install the extension once again even when I had installed it 2 minutes ago. *In other words, chrome.app.isInstalled always return false even when the extension is installed.* Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [chrome.app.isInstalled Always Returns as "false"](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129960):

> `chrome.app.isInstalled` is meant for use by **hosted apps** (which define a set of URLs that encompass the app). Extensions can instead indicate that they're installed already by injecting a DOM node into the page (see second half of https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation#already-installed).

That link describes a strategy for testing if your extension is installed:

1. Have a content script inject a DOM node into every page. This node should have a very specific ID, e.g., `<div id='my-extension-installed-with-id-sdgdthsdfgdtyjufwknsdkos'>`
2. On button press, have your page test if that node exists.
3. If the node exists, the content script is running; therefore, the extension is installed. If it does not exist, assume the extension is not installed.

Injecting a DOM node won't affect the state of `app.isInstalled`. Instead, you check for the existence of the DOM node as proof of the extensions presence.

Comment: Oh I see. I wish that had been more clear in the docs. However, I still think Chrome should have something like chrome.ext.isInstalled to make it easier

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to employ [`externally_connectable`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable).

Since inline install happens from a verified site, you have a set domain on which you want to check that extension exists. Let's say, `example.com` and its subdomains.

Then, you can define the following in your manifest:

```js
"externally_connectable" : {
  "matches" : [
    "*://*.example.com/*"
  ]
}
```

This will expose `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to the `example.com` domain.

You can then set up a message listener for [`onMessageExternal`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessageExternal) in your extension that will reply to [a "ping" from the page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26095346/934239).

Answer (score 1):

Found simple solution, that affects only one page

Check if tab starts with URL of your website, so do some minor DOM change.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (arrayOfTabs) {
    var tab = arrayOfTabs[0];

    if ( tab.url.indexOf('http://yoursite.com') === 0 ){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
                code: 'document.body.classList.add("your_сlass");'
        });
    }
});
```