# chrome extension : can extension communicate with external iframe?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Mu my chrome extension is infact a simple EXTERNAM iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/index.php"></iframe>
```

My goal is that index.php (inside the iframe)can modify

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgetText
```

Is such thing possible with external Iframe ?

reagrds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage). A more detailed answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090563/sending-message-to-background-script/26095346#26095346), but in a nutshell:

1. You need to add `example.com` as an appropriate pattern to `"externally_connectable"` in the manifest.
2. You need to add code to `example.com` page that sends a message to the extension.
3. In your extension's background script, you need to set up a listener for that message, and perform needed operations with it.