# How to use content script and background script to open tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is the flow I'm trying to accomplish:

User clicks button on a regular webpage -> JSON message is sent to the extension -> Extension opens tab.

I understand that content scripts are needed to send the message to the extension:

`contentscript.js`

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

src: [Simple Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple)

`some arbitrary "listener"`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

src: [Simple Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple)

Now, I'm confused about two things:

1. How will `contentscript.js` talk to JSON variables loaded in the webpage?
2. Which file listens to the messages?

Comment: Define "button on a regular webpage". Is this a webpage you control? If not, which buttons should be affected?

Comment: @Xan, sorry, this is a button on my own webpage and I have full access to its actions.

Comment: Then you don't need a content script even. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26095346/934239