# How to launch Chrome packaged app by clicking on a button in a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-app

I have created a Chrome packaged app and when i execute the following line in command prompt, it launches that packaged app:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --load-and-launch-app="chrome-app-path-goes-here"

How can I launch this Chrome app by clicking on a button in a html page?  Any javascript or jQuery way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Requirements:

- specifically whitelisting the domain in the manifest
- knowing the app's ID (you can [pin it for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development))
- having the app already installed.

Take a look at `externally_connectable`: [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26095346/934239).

What you can do is to send a message to the app, which will wake up its Event page.
From there, you can open the app's window as usual.

Comment: As an added bonus, the webpage can detect this way whether the app is installed.

Comment: Note (in case it isn't obvious) that you can't have it so any website can do this, just the ones you whitelist in the app.

Comment: @Ben Well, that's requirement #1 in my answer.

Comment: @Xan, yeah I know, just wanted to point it out a bit more as it can't be wildcarded.