# google extension inline install and Verified not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

1. google.com/webstore  i have add my extension
2. i Have check "This item uses inline install."
3. Websites: chose Verify site
4. google.com/webmasters i have add site and Verifyed.

when i put this code on me site:

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item"href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">

<button onclick="chrome.webstore.install()" id="install-button">Add to Chrome</button>
<script>
if (document.getElementById('extension-is-installed')) {
  document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

i click on button   "Add to Chrome"   install app extension, but when i refresh site  button   "Add to Chrome"  is  display. why? i cant Understanding

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously following the guide at https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

In that case, you missed a step.. Let's look at the code.

```js
if (document.getElementById('extension-is-installed')) {
  document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'none';
}
```

The condition here is whether an element with ID `extension-is-installed` is present on the page. But what adds it?

A step back:

> For example, you could have a content script that targets the installation page:
>
> ```js
> var isInstalledNode = document.createElement('div');
> isInstalledNode.id = 'extension-is-installed';
> document.body.appendChild(isInstalledNode);
> ```

So, you need to add a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that adds that element to the page.

---

However, **I doubt that guide will work**. By default, content scripts execute after DOM is loaded (and therefore, that hiding script has executed). You can make them run at `document_start`, but then `body` does not exist yet.

Let me make an alternative hiding script, based on communicating with the extension [using `"externally_connectable"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361306/934239). Suppose your website is `example.com`, and your extension's ID is `itemID`

1. Add `example.com` to sites you want to be messaged from:

   ```js
     "externally_connectable" : {
       "matches" : [
         "*://*.example.com/*"
       ]
     },
   ```
2. In your background page, prepare for the message from the webpage:

   ```js
   chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
     function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
       if(message.areYouThere) sendResponse(true);
     }
   );
   ```
3. In your page at `example.com`, add a button (hidden by default) and code to show it when appropriate:

```html
    <button onclick="chrome.webstore.install()"
      id="install-button" style="display:none;">
      Add to Chrome
    </button>
    <script>
      if (chrome) {
        // The browser is Chrome, so we may need to show the button
        if(chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.sendMessage) {
          // Some extension is ready to receive messages from us
          // Test it:
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
            "itemID",
            {areYouThere: true},
            function(response) {
              if(response) {
                // Extension is already installed, keep hidden
              } else {
                // No positive answer - it wasn't our extension
                document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'block';
              }
            }
          );
        } else {
          // Extension is not installed, show button
          document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    </script>
```

---

Was requested to add page reload after install. [`chrome.webstore.install` has a callback parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webstore#method-install) specifically for this.

Instead of using `onclick` attribute, assign a function:

```js
document.getElementById('install-button').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  chrome.webstore.install(function() {
    // Installation successful
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: it is working an thx you.  one question , when i Click "Add to chrome" then  click  "Add"  if i add extension  i what to  reload page . were can i put this code : location.reload();

Comment: can  u help me  add   , page reload

Comment: @web404 Edited the answer, but in future please consider asking follow-up questions separately. Take time to look at the site [tour].

Comment: i cant understate were  i pas put   reload code.  for this question  i must create   questions separately? or you can answer here?   i didn't know English well, And excuse me if I did something wrong :(