# How reload page after google extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want  reload page after google extension.

there is background page code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(message.areYouThere) sendResponse(true);
  }
);
```

there is and add button code for webpage:

```
<button onclick="chrome.webstore.install()"
      id="install-button" style="display:none;">
      Add to Chrome
    </button>
    <script>
      if (chrome) {
        // The browser is Chrome, so we may need to show the button
        if(chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.sendMessage) {
          // Some extension is ready to receive messages from us
          // Test it:
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
            "itemID",
            {areYouThere: true},
            function(response) {
              if(response) {
                // Extension is already installed, keep hidden
              } else {
                // No positive answer - it wasn't our extension
                document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'block';
              }
            }
          );
        } else {
          // Extension is not installed, show button
          document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'block';
        }
      }
    </script>
```

i want reload page after google extension.
were i must put this code to do this function

```
document.getElementById('install-button').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  chrome.webstore.install(function() {
    // Installation successful
    location.reload();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*Right there.*

This code [from my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28051898/934239) is a replacement for your `onclick` attribute.

```html
<button id="install-button" style="display:none;">
  Add to Chrome
</button>
<script>
  // Add a click handler
  document.getElementById('install-button').addEventListener(/* ... */);

  // Show if necessary
  if (chrome) {
    /* ... */
  }
</script>
```

(code taken out for brevity)

Comment: It is not reload page, plz chack code

Comment: Sorry, but _no_, I will not help you further. You have to use your brain sometimes - I don't see you trying. "plz put full code" is probably the worst thing you could say on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i am trying many times but it is not working ,  i will crate new question with full code witch i am useing